# How can you coordinate JMS browser and consumer?

Tags: java, jms, message-queue

I am writing a utility program that will process REPLAY queue messages.

What I intend is to use a QueueBrowser to go message by message deciding what needs to be done. I want to stop when I encounter a message that is less than 15 minutes old. This is so that e.g. DB timeouts that occur for a few minutes don't recur. If older, I want to consume the message via a MessageConsumer and place it on the original queue it was on.

There are other rules about what to do. The only way to do this neatly (i.e. without having to repost a message I want to leave on the REPLAY queue, which BTW would increment JMSXDeliveryCount and end up with the message in a different place on the queue) is to coordinate the browser and the consumer.

Thus my question: can this design work? i.e. can I use the consumer on the same message that the browser is working on? Or do I have to bite the bullet and only use a consumer?

Is there a way to consume the message the browser has just returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Regarding the 15 Minute Boundary:

You have the option of defining a message selector so that you will only see messages where the `JMSTimestamp` message header field value is greater than 15 minutes in the past. The spec says that the format of this header field must follow the same format as that returned by `System.currentTimeMillis()`, so all you have to do is make that call and subtract the equivalent of 15 minutes `(15 * 60 * 1000)`:

```
System.currentTimeMillis() - 900000
```

to define the selector. If you choose this option, you will never see messages that do not meet the criteria defined by the selector, which will alleviate some of the issues you raise about message handling.

### Regarding Returning Messages to the Queue:

You have the option of construction the consuming `Session` to use the `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` messaging model. With this form of message acknowledgement, a message may be retrieved from the queue, but is not really considered delivered until the client calls the message's `acknowledge()` method. So if you do not make the `acknowledge()` call, the message will remain available on the queue for other consumers, and it avoids the issues associated with message reposting, delivery-count, message ordering, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Very applicable and will help my effort. I will add one detail I've found since I posted this question: you can get the JMSMessageID from the message being processed in the browser and then use this ID in a consumer to consume the same message when applicable.